# Spring boot, Use same Entity for diferent queries

Tags: java, spring-boot, null, entity

I am trying to set a query result in one entity with diferent quantity of columns, for example:

```java
@Entity
public class Carta1Detalles {

    @Id
    private int panNorequerimiento;
    private String panRutempresa;
    private String panSocio;
    private int panIdsolicitudegreso;
    private int total;
}
```

I have one database table with  15 columns, i make a query and bring only 5 columns, i use my entity very fine. But now i doing another query bringing only 2 columns (2 of 5) but i am trying to use the same entity, i get an error because the query result has diferent type, and that its right.
My question is how i explain to Java that an attribute can be or not mandatory in the result?
For example in Angular you can do:

```
public myvariable?: string;
```

the  '?' means that the value can come in the webservice or not. I want to do something similar in Java.

Its possible?
Thanks

Comment: Actually there confusion in your question. I dont see JPA annotations above your fields in your entity, only `@Id`. So other fields are actually not persisted. At least you should have `javax.persistence.Basic` above these fields. By default fields are optional (nullable). Also I don't see client code where you are querying data.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve your issue is to use DTO projections.

Add all fields in the table to the entity and create a new DTO class with the relevant columns:

```java
class Carta1ListDTO {
    private final int panNorequerimiento;
    private final String panRutempresa;
    // Constructor and getters 
}
```

In the query create the DTO like this

```java
em.createQuery("SELECT new package.name.Carta1ListDTO(c.panNorequerimiento, c.panRutempresa) FROM Carta1Detalles WHERE  ...");
```

You may use different DTOs for each use case (2 fields, 5 fields) or you create one DTO with different constructors.

If you are using Spring Data JPA there's direct support for projections in the framework.

Comment: I am using Spring Data JPA and this demend an ID mandatory in the entity , i will take a look to Projections. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @JhonMasco please vote for answers that are helpful and mark the correct ones as "accepted" (for all of your questions - not particularly this one).